# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am running into the error show below on my app,line 413 points to “`res.json(stat); // return in JSON format.`” in below code, I looked at other posts with similar error but none helped me, why am I hitting this error ?appreciate any guidance on how to fix it?

```
app.post('/api/botjobs.json', function(req, res) {
    // console.log(req.body)
    data = req.body;
    var temp = {};
    temp.radar = data.radar;
    temp.request = data.request;
    if(temp.request == 'cloneradar'){
        temp['params.clonetype'] = data.params.clonetype;
    }
    now = new Date();
    data["updated"] = now;      
    // console.log('DATA:')
    // console.log(data)
    // console.log('TEMP:')
    // console.log(temp)
    botjobs.findOne(temp, {}, { sort:{'_id': -1}}, function(err, findstat){
        // console.log(findstat)
        // console.log(err)
        // console.log("inside botjobs findOne");
        if(findstat != null){
            // console.log('updating entry')
            //console.log(findstat);
            data['numupdated'] = findstat['numupdated']+1;
            // console.log(data);
            botjobs.update({'_id':findstat['_id']},data,{ upsert : true, multi: true },function(err,stat){
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json(stat); // return in JSON format
            });

        }
        else{
            // console.log('creating new entry')
            data["created"] = now;
            data['numupdated'] = 0;
            botjobs.create(data,function(err, stat) {
                // console.log(stat);
                // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json(stat); // return in JSON format. —> line 413 in route.js
            });
        }

    });

});
```

Error:-

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:350:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:134:22)
    at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:595:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.send (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:151:12)
    at ServerResponse.res.json (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:237:15)
    at /app/app/routes.js:413:10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition like this

```
if (err)
{
 res.send(err);
}
else
{
 res.json(stat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `return res.send(err);` in place of `res.send(err);` for each `res.send()`

Answer (score 0):

"Can't set headers after they are sent", this error occurs when u are trying to send something when the response is already sent. The `res.send()` ends the response so you cant send anything after `res.send()`. Why you are receiving this error is because the update call might be returning error and hence the `res.send()` is getting called which is inside if block. 
To avoid the can't set headers error in your case, you need to wrap inside if-else block, like this:

```
if (err){
 res.send(err);
}else{
 res.json(stat);
}
```

This will resolve the cant set headers issue, but your code still might fail because i think your update method is failing.

Comment: but your code still might fail because i think your update method is failing// can you please expand on this?what exactly you meant?

Comment: so  what is meant is even if you apply the code i have written in my answer you might not be getting the desired result because apart from the edit that i suggested if your code would have been workng fine then it should never have went to the if condition for error. It went there because you had error somwhere in your `botjobs.update()` statement. And because you didnt handle the error correctly it tried to send response after sending error. So if you can get your botjob.update right, ur code will never fail but u shud still apply my edit as it handles error properly.